# static_cast from 'QgsVectorLayer *' to 'QgsMapLayer *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed

Tags: c++, casting, qgis

Class `QgsVectorlayer` derives from base class `QgsMapLayer` which derives from base class `QObject`. I want to cast a `QgsVectorlayer` object to a base class. This should easily be possbile but I get an error and don't understand why.

The annex to the (probably not unimportant) error message is:

> ...qgsgeometry.h:46:7: note: 'QgsVectorLayer' is incomplete

Line 46 contains only the `QgsVectorLayer` class definition:

```
class QgsVectorLayer;
```

(see source https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/geometry/qgsgeometry.h#L46)

This is my use case:
I need to pass the argument variable `vectorLayer` in my adapted function `QgsOgrProvider::extent(QgsVectorLayer* vectorLayer) const` to another function as type `QgsMapLayer*` or `QObject*` which `QgsVectorlayer` is derived from. My understanding is that this should automatically be type casted or I could cast it using `static_cast<type>(variable)` but I get an error and don't understand why.

The definition of QgsVectorLayer:

```
class CORE_EXPORT QgsVectorLayer : public QgsMapLayer, public QgsExpressionContextGenerator, ...
{...}
```

(full source: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/vector/qgsvectorlayer.h)

The definition of QgsMapLayer:

```
class CORE_EXPORT QgsMapLayer : public QObject
{...}
```

(full source: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/src/core/qgsmaplayer.h)

My code that throws errors:

```
QgsOgrProvider::extent(QgsVectorLayer* vectorLayer) const
{
...

QgsMapLayer * mapLayer=static_cast< QgsMapLayer*>(vectorLayer);
// error: static_cast from 'QgsVectorLayer *' to 'QObject *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed; qgsgeometry.h:46:7: note: 'QgsVectorLayer' is incomplete

QObject * mapObject=static_cast< QObject*>(vectorLayer);
// error: static_cast from 'QgsVectorLayer *' to 'QgsMapLayer *', which are not related by inheritance, is not allowed; qgsgeometry.h:46:7: note: 'QgsVectorLayer' is incomplete

QObject * mapObject2=new QObject();
// error: assigning to 'QObject *' from incompatible type 'QgsVectorLayer *'
mapObject2=vectorLayer;

...
}
```

Comment: i guess it refuses the cast because the type is incomplete, try to include QgsVectorLayer instead of using a forward declaration only

Comment: Are you sure the full definition of class `QgsVectorLayer` is visible to the compiler at the point at which you use `static_cast< QgsVectorLayer *>`.  If only a forward declaration is visible that would explain the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of the class is missing at the point where the `static_cast` is used. Just because the definition of the class exists in some header file doesn't mean that the compiler automatically knows it everywhere the class is referenced. Whichever header file defines this class was not `#include`d, so the only thing that the compiler knows is that the class has been declared.

> Line 46 contains only the QgsVectorLayer class definition:
>
> class QgsVectorLayer;

The translation unit `#include`d this header file, directly or indirectly.

> The definition of QgsVectorLayer:
>
> class CORE_EXPORT QgsVectorLayer : public QgsMapLayer, public
> QgsExpressionContextGenerator, ... {...}

And this header file was not `#include`d, directly or indirectly.

You'll need to figure out how to correctly `#include` the required header files.